# Prepend to file without temp file by manipulating inode?

Tags: file, prepend, inode

Prepending to a large file is difficult, since it requires pushing all 
other characters forward. However, could it be done by manipulating 
the inode as follows?:

- Allocate a new block on disk and fill with your prepend data.
- Tweak the inode to tell it your new block is now the first 
  block, and to bump the former first block to the second block 
  position, former second block to the third position, and so on.

I realize this still requires bumping blocks forward, but it should be 
more efficient than having to use a temp file.

I also realize the new first block will be a "short" block (not all the data in the block is part of the file), since your prepend data is unlikely to be exactly the same size as a block.

Or, if inode blocks are simply linked, it would require very little 
work to do the above.

NOTE: my last experience directly manipulating disk data was with a 
Commodore 1541, so my knowledge may be a bit out of date...

Answer (score 1):

Modern-day operating systems should not allow a user to do that, as inode data structures are specific to the underlying file system.

If your file system/operating system supports it, you could make your file a sparse file by prepending empty data at the beginning, and then writing to the sparse blocks. In theory, this should give you what you want.

YMMV, I'm just throwing around ideas. ;)

Comment: I agree that inodes should be hidden.  We are looking for a way for the OS to do the inode fiddling for us.  Since a file is a tree, inserting at the beginning or anywhere else should be as fast as inserting only at the end by appending to the file.

Comment: If the inode's extent book-keeping structure is tree-like (which depends on the FS), then the "sparse file" prepend move should -- in theory;) -- do the trick. Have you given it a try?

Comment: IIUC, you suggest to reserve 50mb of sparse unused space at the beginning of the file, record somewhere how much of the file to ignore when reading, and when you have a new MB to prepend, decrease it to 49 and write at the end of the sparse section.  That should work, but it would be nice to be able to insert at any point in the file.

Answer (score 0):

This could work! Yes, userland programs should not be mucking around with inodes. Yes, it necessarily depends on whatever scheme used to track blocks by whatever file systems implement this function. None of this is a reason to reject this proposal out of hand.

Here is how it could work.

For the sake of illustration, suppose we have an inode that tracks blocks by an array of direct pointers to data blocks. Further suppose that the inode carries a starting-offset and and ending-offset that apply to the first and last blocks respectively, so you can have less-than-full blocks both at the beginning and end of a file.

Now, suppose you want to prepend data. It would go something like this.

```
IF (new data will fit into unused space in first data block)
  write the new data to the beginning of the first data block
  update the starting-offset
  return success indication to caller

try to allocate a new data block
IF (block allocation failed)
  return failure indication to caller

shift all existing data block pointers down by one
write the ID of the newly-allocated data block into the first slot of the array
write as much data as will fit into the second block (the old first block)
write the rest of data into the newly-allocated data block, shifted to the end    
starting-offset := (data block size - length of data in first block) 
return success indication to caller
```